# Limiting the number of rows joined in SQL while using inner join,limit and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, inner-join, limit

I have many tables which require joins before fetching data to display.

Also I am using inner join and I just want to show first 20 results.

So the problem is that at present the query is scanning the whole table because it will sort first and then extract the top 20 rows, and I can't make the column I want to sort as primary index though it is indexed.

The second thing is that also the query uses Joins so is there a way that I get the top 20 results from parent table(sorted column is present in parent table itself) and then reduce the rows being joined and thus reducing the join time?
Query is like:

```
select distinct patientFirstName as patientFirstName, patientLastName 
as patientLastName from EncounterInformationBean inner join LastName 
ON
EncounterInformationBean.id=LastName.uid
where
patientFirstName like key and isActive=1 order by patientFirstName
LIMIT 20
```

key is a variable name which is of string type.

Any optimization strategy for the problem is appreciated.

I already indexed the column to be sorted(though not as primary key) but the main problem is join.

One way can be denormalization but there are many columns to be displayed.

Comment: No one can help you without seeing the query and an understanding of the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the query.

Comment: Please qualify each column with the table that it is in.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And tell us what `like key` is intended to do.  And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I'm assuming that `EncounterInformationBean` table have more data than `LastName` table. Where is `isActive` column from? And are the index consists of at least any columns from your `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Another question, on which table you want to impose the `LIMIT`? Because you mention _"is there a way that I get the top 20 results from parent table"_ . If so, you can sub-query the parent table to return top 20 row first then join it with another table. I think it will be quicker.

Comment: @tcadidot0 you're right.. EncounterInformationBean has more  data..isActive is in EncounterInformationBean table itself.. No you suggest me the indexes which I should use.

Comment: Like @RickJames suggested, index `patientFirstName and isActive`. And I add, index `EncounterInformationBean.id and LastName.uid` too if not yet been indexed.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `DISTINCT`
- Spell `ORDER BY` correctly
- What the heck is `like key`
- Have `INDEX(isActive, patientFirstName)`

Comment: yea my bad it was order by..and key is a string .. Is there any way to avoid joining the whole table?

Comment: @abhihacker02 - Without knowing which column is in which table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`), I can't finish helping you optimize the query.